# Find, grep gzipped file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I want to do grep some lines from files I'm finding with the `find` command. The files are zipped though. How can I find them, de-compress them, do my grep search and put my results into a new file.

```
zcat find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*' | grep 'vid=123'
```

is not working, give the error:

```
 gzip: invalid option -- 'e'
 Try `gzip --help' for more information.
```

I assume though that if it were working, to save I should add

```
> ~/found_logs.20140226.txt
```

Is this correct?

What is wrong with my `zcat` and `grep` string?

Comment: Err... you are trying to `zcat` the files "find", "/my_home", "-name" and whatever matches "\*log.20140226\*"? Because that's what you are stating... have you perhaps forgotten backticks / `$()`?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*' -exec zgrep -H 'vid=123' {} \; > results
```

Or, if you want to find files with lines containing your 2 different strings, in any order:

```
find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*' -exec zegrep -H "vid=23.*mid=2|mid=2.*vid=23" {} \; > results
```

**Notes:**

The `-H` option causes `grep` to print the name of the matching file.

I use **z**grep to handle compressed files, and then **ze**grep to handle the regular expression of "pattern|pattern" wherein I specify the search strings in both possible orders on the line, so I am effectively searching for EITHER of two patterns, namely "vid followed by mid" OR "mid followed by vid".

Comment: `… -exec zgrep -lH 'vid=123' {} +` might be a little faster.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, it might, thank you. Depends if OP wants to see the matched string or just the filename though - I am not sure. Or I may be old and have missed something :-)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I want the lines the grep matches put into the new file.

Comment: Does that change this method somehow?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: It's the `+` that provides the optimization, as it packs as many filename arguments as will fit into each (likely only 1) invocation of `zgrep` (rather than invoking `zgrep` once for every file); @kojiro probably meant `-h` rather than `-l`, as it is `-h` that suppresses prepending the filename to each output line (which `grep` does by default if multiple filenames are specified).

Comment: I see, I thought @kojiro was referring to the `-l` which just prints the filename and quits rather than all the matching strings and is therefore faster. I am unfamiliar with the `+` and it doesn't even work on my Mac so I cannot advise - maybe it is a GNU find addition.

Comment: @mklement0 is there a way I can print/tail this to screen before saving so I can see if it's grepping the lines correctly?

Comment: Change the "> results" into "| more" and press spacebar for next screenful.

Comment: @thomas: If you want to simultaneously output to stdout and capture to a file, replace `> results` with `| tee results`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: `+` _does_ work on OSX: Try something simple such as `find . -name '*.txt' -exec echo {} +`. Again, this is where the optimization lies, but the side effect with `grep` is that filenames are prepended to matching lines, which the `-h` counteracts; can't speak for @kojiro, but I'm pretty sure that's what he intended.

Comment: @mklement0 `find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*'  -exec zgrep -H 'vid=123' {} | more` gives me the error `find: missing argument to `-exec'`. I expected to see a bunch of lines of matches. Have I got a piece wrong?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 1. I misunderstood this answer, but had I understood it, I would've said `-h` instead of `-l`. 2. How old is your mac? `-exec +` has been in the stock `find` of OS X for at least the last two versions.

Comment: @thomas: Yes, now you're missing `\;` before the `|` - it (or its more efficient alternative, `+`) is needed to terminate the `-exec` command; thus: `find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*'  -exec zgrep -H 'vid=123' {} \; | more` or `find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*'  -exec zgrep -H 'vid=123' {} + | more`

Comment: @mklement0 No, I don't want the names of the files, but the actual results of each match from all the searched files.

Comment: I am running Mavericks - bang up to date. When I tried initially, I terminated the command with "zgrep ... {} + \;" and it failed, whereas I now see it must be terminated with "zgrep ... {} +" and no trailing semi-colon and it does work.

Comment: @thomas: With `-H`, you get *both*: `<filename>:<matching line>`. If you don't want the `<filename>:` prefix, use `-h` instead of `-H`.

Comment: @mklement0 Awesome. Just one last question. How could I add one additional grep? I want to also only find files like `grep 'mid=2'`?

Comment: If you want to find files that contain EITHER "vid=23" OR "mid=2", replace the `zgrep` with `zegrep "vid=23|mid=2"`

Comment: @mklement0 Oh, no. I meant vid=23 AND mid=2.

Comment: Will answer later if possible - am in theatre.

Comment: @thomas If you only want to find lines containing *both* strings (in any order), use something like `zegrep "vid=23.*mid=2|mid=2.*vid=23"`; depending on your input, you may have to refine the regex to rule out false positives.

Comment: No. OP wants to find files containing both patterns anywhere, not necessarily both patterns on same line - I think.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to find lines that match both `vid=123` and `mid=2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zgrep`

```
cd /my_home
zgrep 'vid=123' *log.20140226*
```

Comment: You've single-quoted the glob, which prevents the intended pathname expansion. Even then you're only matching files _directly_ located in `/my_home`, whereas the original `find` command would process the entire subtree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
zcat `find /my_home -name '*log.20140226*'`|grep 'vid=123'
```

Without the backticks `find /my_home ...` is being sent as arguments to `zcat`, when you want the output of the `find` to be sent as arguments to `zcat`.

Comment: Can you explain how this works please? Why does it need the backticks? Thanks!

Comment: @thomas: The backticks cause the command they enclose to be executed and its stdout output -- a list of file paths, in this case -- to be passed as arguments to `zcat`. This technique is called _command substitution_ (as an aside: the preferred syntax nowadays is `$(...)`). That said, this approach is not advisable here, because filenames with embedded spaces would not be handled correctly.

Comment: there won't be any spaces in the filenames, and the other upvoted selection doesn't work.